# Displaying information bar in outlook application

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-object-model

I have developed an outlook plugin using atl. I want to show some information to user using yellow bar which comes just below ribbon of application. 
I have found one class for that in interop, but dont know how to use it. Its **olkinfobar**

If i create its instance than how to i bound it to application.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olkinfobarclass.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom form to use this control.

Instead, you need to develop an Outlook form region or create an adjacent window. See [Adjacent Windows In Outlook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2010/06/01/adjacent-windows-in-outlook.aspx) for more information about subclassing Outlook windows using Windows API functions.